# Accessing remote sharepoint server

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-designer

I have written an IronPython script that generates a xml file that contains the metadata of a site and the document libraries that it has. I use the Microsoft.SharePoint dll extensively. Is it possible to run this script and generate the metadata of a site that is hosted in a remote server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, if you are using the SharePoint Object Model and reference the SharePoint dll, it needs to run locally on the server.
In order to access remote SharePoint server, you will have to use the Web Services interface instead.